# How to open android app after kill every X seconds?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app which will be able to open every x seconds or minutes even when the app is killed(by killed I mean removing it from task-manager or quitting it by pressing the back-button). I know that this is kind of spamming, but this is just a **test app**, only for **learning purposes**.

By opening every x seconds, I mean that the MainActivity of the app is poping up every x seconds to the user, always when the user is **not** inside the app. It has to happen always even when the app is killed.

Do you think that something like this will be allowed by android and if yes, how can I programme it?(I was thinking about a foreground-service)

Comment: If you can do this it'll be with [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

Comment: An app opening up frequently without User interaction is against the Android framework's design principles. It might be possible to acheive this on a rooted phone. This will definitely not be possible on a non rooted phone. The best you can do on a non rooted phone is have a notification pop up ever so often.

Comment: Why would this be useful in a test app?

Comment: @Swagger 68 Do you think it would work with `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED`, I know it's not the same, but it is nearly similar?

Comment: You will be able to  register a listener for that event but you will not be able to automatically open up your app everytime the listener is triggered on a non rooted phone.

Comment: @PiotrSuchodolski Actually, Calling apps like whatsapp do pop up on your screen without User Interaction. So you should be able to do this!

Comment: @PiotrSuchodolski Even if you kill whatsapp as in remove it from recently used, it still allows people to call you and put a pop up on your screen. So this is very much possible using Android.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you are not able to do that. After your app is killed, it's not on the memory anymore. This space is given back to android System. The app itself has a lifecycle. You do not have much control after it's finished.

I believe you won't be able to call your application after X seconds, BUT there's something you can take a look: Broadcast receivers

You can make you app respond to some system events, like: chager connected / low battery / conect to a network... There might be some event you would like to work with

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: Hello, thank you for your solution, what would the code snippet look like, if I would like to do this with `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED`, I mean the code like `if battery changed than open MainActivity`